# Header tag based on position in xml

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I would like to produce a h1 to h3 tag for a header based on its section position

the xml is in the format

```
<sections>
        <section>
            <header>section 1 header</header>
            <image alt="section 1 image alt">imagename.filetype</image>
            <content>section 1 content</content>
        </section>
        <section>
            <header>section 2 header</header>
            <image alt="section 2 image alt">imagename.filetype</image>
            <content>section 2 content</content>
        </section>
        <section>
            <header>section 3 header</header>
            <image alt="section 3 image alt">imagename.filetype</image>
            <content>section 3 content</content>
        </section>
    </sections>
```

my output would want to be like

```
<div>
<h1> section 1 header</h1>
<img alt="section 1 image alt" src="imagename.filename"/>
section 1 content
</div>

<div>
<h2> section 2 header</h2>
<img alt="section 2 image alt" src="imagename.filename"/>
section 2 content
</div>

<div>
<h3> section 3 header</h3>
<img alt="section 3 image alt" src="imagename.filename"/>
section 3 content
</div>
```

is there a simple way to do this? any ideas appreciated!

kind thanks Treemonkey

update:

```
<xsl:template mode="section" match="section">    
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="header" select="header">
            <xsl:with-param name="position">h<xsl:value-of select="position()"/></xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:apply-templates>   
        <img alt="{image/@alt}" src="{image}" />
        <xsl:value-of select="content"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template mode="header" match="header">  
    <xsl:param name="position">0</xsl:param>  
        <xsl:element name="{$position}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:element>    
    </xsl:template>
```

using the above xslt which is slightly updated version of khachik post

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete solution that is completely in the spirit of XSLT (push style). :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is a complete solution which is entirely in push style**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="section">
  <div>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </div>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="header">
  <xsl:element name="h{count(../preceding-sibling::section)+1}">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="sections|content">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<sections>
    <section>
        <header>section 1 header</header>
        <image alt="section 1 image alt">imagename.filetype</image>
        <content>section 1 content</content>
    </section>
    <section>
        <header>section 2 header</header>
        <image alt="section 2 image alt">imagename.filetype</image>
        <content>section 2 content</content>
    </section>
    <section>
        <header>section 3 header</header>
        <image alt="section 3 image alt">imagename.filetype</image>
        <content>section 3 content</content>
    </section>
</sections>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
    <div>
       <h1>section 1 header</h1>
       <image alt="section 1 image alt">imagename.filetype</image>
section 1 content
    </div>
    <div>
       <h2>section 2 header</h2>
       <image alt="section 2 image alt">imagename.filetype</image>
section 2 content
    </div>
    <div>
       <h3>section 3 header</h3>
       <image alt="section 3 image alt">imagename.filetype</image>
section 3 content
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that just just what i was after!, don't understand it at the moment but will work it out. ah so it counts the headers before an adds 1. got ya thanks Dimitre

Comment: +1 Good answer. It would match exactly the desired output adding a rule for `image` and even dropping the indentity rule and the rule overwriting the built-in rule for elements.

Answer (score 0):

This not an answer since it looks ugly, but is too long for a comment. I'm not sure this is the best way to do it, but:

```
<xsl:template match="section">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="./header">
        <xsl:with-param name="position"><xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
         </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    <!-- section stuff here -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="header">
    <xsl:param name="position">0</xsl:param>
    <xsl:variable name="tagname"><xsl:value-of select="concat('h', $position)"></xsl:value-of></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:element name="{$tagname}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

A note: I don't think heading depending on the position is a good idea. DocBook and another languages use the section level to put the appropriate header tag.

Comment: this is similar to my original idea may try it with a little edit :)